# Facebook request in Android - profile picture is not available anymore

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In an Android App I have the following code:

```
private void requestDataFromFb() {

    Callback callback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            AppLog.Log(TAG, "Facebook Response ::" + response + "");
            Utility.closeprocess(Login.this);
            loadImage(response);
        }
    };

    String graphPath = "me";
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fields",
            "id,picture.height(250),gender,first_name,last_name,age_range");

    Request mRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), graphPath,
            bundle, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
    RequestAsyncTask task = Request.executeBatchAsync(mRequest);
    if (task == null) {
        AppLog.Log(TAG, "task is null");
    } else {
        AppLog.Log(TAG, task.getStatus() + "");
    }
}
```

It's been working fine and I am getting the paths to the user's profile picture. However, after some time the paths don't work anymore. One cannot see the picture of the first users. When I enter the [URL](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p320x320/10421478_10152754480624192_2619262604918760263_n.jpg?oh=da81d9588981ad55a2b4552f9ca3b296&oe=54D967CB&__gda__=1423121754_90748674948822b48ab448680998cc18) in my browser I get:

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #50.3d1431b5.1424197137.a584ec67
```

And when using the Graph API Explorer of Facebook I get a [different URL](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/s480x480/10351825_10152078745080863_8547512756363521244_n.jpg?oh=8c7d73b0f93d62beda1aae9e7ef9214d&oe=55538556&__gda__=1431252099_838e83bf71c86ebd87590b9b961625b8) for the picture.

I do not know if that has something to do with the fact that the user has changed their profile picture or something else, and how I could solve this issue.

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That is by design. You get back a CDN url. They are not valid forever

Comment: Hmmm how often should I update the path?

Comment: Would it be better to update the field of image path in my mysql Database with     https://graph.facebook.com/USERS_ID/picture?height=250 and not the fbcdn...?

Comment: I am using the Graph api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture) and I never had any issue with it so I think using http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture should solve your problem .